# Oracle SQL - Generate Pattern Based Unique UserID

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a requirement to generate a unique UserID using an Oracle SQL procedure. For a user, `John Smith`, the UserID should be generated using the below conditions:

1. First letter of the first name + last name: `jsmith`
2. In case there is another user with the same name: First letter of the first name + second letter of the first name + last name: `josmith`
3. For another duplicate: First letter of the first name + second letter of the first name + third letter of the first name + last name: `johsmith`
4. For another duplicate: First letter of the first name + second letter of the first name + third letter of the first name + fourth letter of the first name + last name: `johnsmith`
5. We keep iterating until we have exhausted all the letters of the first name
6. When we have run out of the letters of the first name, and there are still duplicates, we append a number at the end: `johnsmith1`
7. For further duplicates, we keep incrementing the number at the end: `johnsmith1`, `johnsmith2`, etc.

I am looking for ideas as a starting point for an optimised and scalable solution.

Comment: How about just using an auto increment column here?  I mean, your suggested logic is complex and will be hard to implement and maintain.  If you really want an identifier which is guaranteed to be unique, then maybe assign a UUID.

Comment: This ID will be used for applications like Active Directory, so needs to be user-friendly. I had implemented a similar logic but it just followed jsmith1, jsmith2, jsmith3, etc. I know it's complicated, but that's what the requirement is unfortunately.

Comment: Then you will probably have to write a complex before insert trigger.

Comment: Does it really have to be based on first and last name? We are using artificial unique identifiers (logins) like X001234  (one letter + 7 digits) or AB34YQ (2 letters + 2 digits + 2 letters). None of the users complain that it is not user friendly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `UUID` are very popular, but somehow harder to remember than the accounts formed from the abbreviated names.

Answer (score 0):

This query produces the first 100 account name proposals based on the first and last name (feel free to adjust the count of generated options).

```
with acc as (
select rownum id, 'John' fname, 'Smith' lname from dual connect by level <=100
) 
select 
id,
case when id <= length(fname) then 
substr(fname,1,id)||lname
else
fname||lname||to_char(id-length(fname)) end as account_name
from acc;

        ID ACCOUNT_NAME                                    
---------- -------------------------------------------------
         1 JSmith                                            
         2 JoSmith                                           
         3 JohSmith                                          
         4 JohnSmith                                         
         5 JohnSmith1                                        
         6 JohnSmith2                                        
         7 JohnSmith3                                        
         8 JohnSmith4                                        
         9 JohnSmith5  
 ....
```

If you have a table with assigned account names, say `user_accounts`, you may open this cursor and fetch the first row. This will provide a new free account name based on your rules.

```
with acc as (
  select rownum id, 'John' fname, 'Smith' lname from dual connect by level <=100
), acc2 as (
select 
  id,
  case when id <= length(fname) then 
   substr(fname,1,id)||lname
  else
   fname||lname||to_char(id-length(fname)) end as account_name
from acc)
select id, account_name from acc2
where account_name not in 
    (select account_name from user_accounts)
order by id;
```